# Add column for percentage of total to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that I am doing a `groupby()` on to get the counts on a column's values. I am trying to add an additional column for "Percentage of Total".  I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

I've looked at a few groupby options, but can't seem to find anything that fits.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
              DAYSLATE
DAYSLATE          
-7 days          1
-5 days          2
-3 days          8
-2 days          9
-1 days         45
0 days         589
1 days          33
2 days           8
3 days          16
4 days          14
5 days          16
6 days           2
7 days           6
8 days           2
9 days           2
10 days          1
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
df['DAYSLATE_pct'] = df.DAYSLATE / df.DAYSLATE.sum()
```

**Option 2**
Use `pd.value_counts` instead of `groupby`

```
pre_df.DAYSLATE.value_counts(normalize=True)
```